# Up-to-date list of built-in Core Image filters?

Tags: ios, macos, core-image, cifilter

Apple's [`Core Image Filter Reference`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004346), which describes all of the built-in `CIFilter`s, is marked as "no longer being updated".

[Looks like](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/cifilterref_revhx.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004346-CH2-SW1) it was last updated in 2016. Since then, WWDC videos for 2017 and 2018 have announced additional filters (which, indeed, don't appear on this page).

Does anybody know of a more up-to-date list of built-in Core Image filters?

(Question has also been asked, but so far not answered, on the [Apple Dev Forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/108585).)

Comment: AFAIK, the only reliable way of finding out is querying available filters and their parameters as described here -  https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_concepts/ci_concepts.html

Comment: Thanks, @MaximVolgin. Better than nothing, for sure -- though the former textual descriptions and illustrative images were very helpful.

Comment: I've been offline for a few days and am just getting caught up. I have an app that actually checks that a particular filter exists on an iOS device (I've never tried it on macOS but it's a CoreImage query, not an OS one. It's based on something I found written in Swift 2 (mine is Swift 4). You can get the names, attributes, max/min/default values for the attributes... pretty much everything *but* a filter description. The output of this query is a dictionary, so you'll have to either wade through a dump or modify the code for your use. I'll try to post it in the next day if you want it.

Comment: Sounds helpful, @dfd!

Answer (score 6):

I've created a [website called CIFilter.io](https://cifilter.io) which lists all the built-in CIFilters and a [companion app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cifilter-io/id1457458557?mt=8) which you can use to try the filters out if you like. This should have all the up to date CIFilter information - I've updated it for iOS 13 and intend to continue to keep it updated.

More info about the project is available [in this blog post](https://noahgilmore.com/blog/cifilterio/).

Answer (score 3):

I created a small project to query an iOS device and (1) list out all available filters and (2) list everything about each input attributes. This project can be found [here](https://github.com/justdfd/CoreImageFilters).

The relevant code:

```
var ciFilterList = CIFilter.filterNames(inCategories: nil)
```

This line creates a `[String]` of all available filters. If you only wish for all available filters of category "CICategoryBlur", replace the `nil` with it.

```
print("=======")
print("List of available filters")
print("-------")
for ciFilterName in ciFilterList {
    print(ciFilterName)
}
print("-------")
print("Total: " + String(ciFilterList.count))
```

Pretty self-explanatory. When I ran this on an iPad mini running iOS 12.0.1, 207 filters were listed. NOTE: I have never tried this on macOS, but since it really doesn't use `UIKit` I believe it will work.

```
let filterName = "CIZoomBlur"
let filter = CIFilter(name: filterName)
print("=======")
print("Filter Name: " + filterName)
let inputKeys = filter?.inputKeys
if inputKeys?.count == 0 {
   print("-------")
   print("No input attributes.")
} else {
   for inputKey in inputKeys! {
       print("-------")
       print("Input Key: " + inputKey)
       if  let attribute = filter?.attributes[inputKey] as? [String: AnyObject],
           let attributeClass = attribute[kCIAttributeClass] as? String,
           let attributeDisplayName = attribute["CIAttributeDisplayName"] as? String,
           let attributeDescription = attribute[kCIAttributeDescription] as? String {
               print("Display name: " + attributeDisplayName)
               print("Description: " + attributeDescription)
               print("Attrbute type: " + attributeClass)
               switch attributeClass {
               case "NSNumber":
                   let minimumValue = (attribute[kCIAttributeSliderMin] as! NSNumber).floatValue
                   let maximumValue = (attribute[kCIAttributeSliderMax] as! NSNumber).floatValue
                   let defaultValue = (attribute[kCIAttributeDefault] as! NSNumber).floatValue
                   print("Default value: " + String(defaultValue))
                   print("Minimum value: " + String(minimumValue))
                   print("Maximum value: " + String(maximumValue))
               case "CIColor":
                   let defaultValue = attribute[kCIAttributeDefault] as! CIColor
                   print(defaultValue)
               case "CIVector":
                   let defaultValue = attribute[kCIAttributeDefault] as! CIVector
                   print(defaultValue)
               default:
                   // if you wish, just dump the variable attribute to look at everything!
                   print("No code to parse an attribute of type: " + attributeClass)
                   break
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
print("=======")
```

Again, fairly self-explanatory. The app I'm writing only works with filters using a single `CIImage` and with attributes restricted to `NSNumber`, `CIColor`, and `CIVector`, so things *will* fall to the default part of the `switch` statement. However, it should get you started! If you wish to see the "raw" version, jut look at the `attribute` variable.

Finally, I'd recommend something developed by Simon Gladman called Filterpedia. It's an iPad app (restricted to landscape) that allows you to experiment with pretty much all available filters along with all attributes with default/max/min values. Be aware of two things though. (1) It's written in Swift 2, but the is a Swift 4 fork [here](https://github.com/rhoeper/Filterpedia-Swift4). (2) There are also numerous custom filters using custom `CIKernels`.

Comment: Thanks, @dfd! I'll also give FIlterpedia a spin.